# JSON-File - print multiple informations

Tags: html, css, json

I have a few problems with my JSON-Data. I am building a website, where the user should be able to create recipes. For that, he can type in a name, ingredients and the cooking-process. On my Website, the user can find recipes and subscribe to them. The problem is, that there are multiple ingredients but on my website, there is always just the first items...its like its not reading the whole array.

My JSON looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c2ff33debbe541cdc500594"),
    "subscriber" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2ff340ebbe541cdc500595"),
                    "userID" : "5c2ff31bfa14ec17b8ad10c4",
                    "username" : "Dominik"
            }
    ],
    "titel" : "Spaghetti Bolognese",
    "theme" : "Meat",
    "ingredients" : "Noodles, Meat, Sauce",
    "discription" : "Cook Noodles and meat. Cook the sauce."}
```

As you can see, the system is saving the the informations correctly. My Code to print all of this is like that

```
<div id="content">
<% if(subscriptions.length>0) { %>
    <% for(var i=0; i < subscriptions.length; i++) { %>
        <% if("") { %>
        <%} else {%>
        <div id="recipe_titel"><%=subscriptions[i].titel%></div>
        <div id="recipe_ingredients"><%=subscriptions[i].ingredients%></div>
        <div id="recipe_discription"><%=subscriptions[i].discription%></div>
            <td><button type="submit" class="button_unsubscribe" value="<%=subscriptions[i]._id%> <%=subscriptions[i].recipeID%>" id="button_small">Subscribe</button></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

On my Website the result is

```
Spaghetti
Bolognese
Noodles,
```

I have no clue, why the system is not printing the right result...it is saved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

firstly it's not clear, where you even try to use `subscriptions[i].ingredients`

More then that, `"ingredients" : "Noodles, Meat, Sauce"` is not an array, maybe you should use `"ingredients" : ["Noodles", "Meat", "Sauce"]` ?

Comment: I am sorry, there was a little typing-mistakte. I corrected it.
<div id="recipe_ingredients"><%=subscriptions[i].ingredients%></div>

Comment: Ok, ckeck your string then, try to remove spaces and commas firstly, what is the result? Then try to add space, check, then comma, check, then second space, etc. I think,there may be some unreadable letter, such as line break...